# Can't access our Buffalo Network attached storage device

Tags: networking, samba, authentication

I get a box asking for the user name and password, which I correctly supply, but it won't accept them. I just verified that the user name and password work on an old 10.04 machine.

Comment: Can you add some more detail? Perhaps a log or something from the buffalo?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu **11.10** or **12.04**?

Comment: This is tagged 'samba' - in what way is it related?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with my NAS.  Just that mine is dlink DNS-323.

Look at my post to see if it helps in something:

[Network authentication not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127223/12-04-network-authentication-not-working)

Regards.

Comment: This was solved by an answer to another post on this forum. http://askubuntu.com/questions/127223/12-04-network-authentication-not-working

Comment: @NTMexico please click the little green tick below the voting buttons to accept the answer. Thanks.