# How do I mount an Active Directory Windows share?

Tags: nautilus, windows, samba, active-directory

How can i mount Active Directory Windows share in Ubuntu 12.04?
In 10.04 it was easy mounting a Windows server share i nautilus, but it keeps telling me that my credentials is wrong. And they are not!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. I got the solution from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127223/12-04-network-authentication-not-working).

```
in /etc/samba/smb.conf add the following to the bottom of the [global]
section:

client lanman auth = yes
client ntlmv2 auth = no
```

Worked perfectly after that.