# Nautilus can't mount Active Directory share

Tags: server, mount, permissions, nautilus, samba

"Connect to Server" in Nautilus doesn't connect to our Active Directory shares: I get an infinite loop of user/password challenges. I can access the same shares with a "sudo mount" and "smbclient", so it seems to be a Nautilus problem.

Background: Just upgraded from 12.04 to 16.04. I had used Centrify to join to our Active Directory, but now opted for a "bare metal" approach, so followed the SSSD and Active Directory installation guide. "sudo mount" and "smbclient", as well as login of AD-authenticated users, work perfectly, so the AD join appears to have been a success.

Things I've tried:

- Googling. Lots of similar-sounding problems, but no solutions that work for me.
- Look in /var/log/auth.log: nothing.
- Look in /var/log/syslog: just an entry "Password dialog cancelled". (Indeed I did.)
- Run Nautilus with debug options, according to "Debugging GNOME" instructions. (FYI: have to kill the running Nautilus first: "nautilus -q".) No debug output.
- Plow through the "Debugging Samba" instructions. No help.

Additional information:

- Samba versions:

  ```
  libnss-winbind 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 samba install ok installed
  libpam-winbind 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 samba install ok installed
  libsmbclient 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 samba install ok installed
  libwbclient0 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 samba install ok installed
  python-samba 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 samba install ok installed
  samba 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1  install ok installed
  samba-common 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 samba install ok installed
  samba-common-bin 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 samba install ok installed
  samba-dsdb-modules 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 samba install ok installed
  samba-libs 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 samba install ok installed
  samba-vfs-modules 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 samba install ok installed
  smbclient 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 samba install ok installed
  winbind 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 samba install ok installed
  ```
- Remote server info:

  ```
  OS=[Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 9600] Server=[Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3]
  ```

**Edit**

It appears I'm the victim of a [well-known and long-standing bug in GVfs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/510059). There are a number of hacks to try to get around these, [nicely summarised in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50197/cannot-connect-to-samba-share-from-nautilus). However, none of these worked for me, I assume because my smb.conf specifies "security = ads" (Active Directory Server). In any case, the hacks rely on enabling weak authentication schemes, which is a bad idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I mount an Active Directory Windows share?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/128393/how-do-i-mount-an-active-directory-windows-share)

Answer (score 0):

Until I find a better fix, I've decided to forget about mounting network shares in Nautilus, and to use a script to do a standard mount instead. I include the script, if anyone's interested:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo Enter network user:
    echo -n "Name [$USER]: "
    read USR
    if [ "$USR" = "" ]; then
        USR="$USER"
    fi
    echo -n "Password: "
    read -s PWD
    echo

    SERVER="your server name here"
    SHARES="your share names here"

    for SHR in $SHARES; do
        ERR=$(sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,username=$USR,password=$PWD,uid=$USER //$SERVER/$SHR ~/Shares/$SHR 2>&1)
        if [ "$ERR" = "" ]; then
            ERR="OK"
        fi
        echo $SHR: $ERR
    done
```